# How to correctly quote a command with parameters in a Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line-arguments, batch-processing, command-prompt

I am attempting to open multiple PDF files in multiple tabs in multiple windows using PDF X-Change Viewer, which has [command line options](http://help.tracker-software.com/EUM/default.aspx?pageid=PDFXView25:command_line_options). All PDF files listed in the same line open within the same window.

To allow the script to proceed without waiting for the windows created on each line to close, I am attempting to use `start`. However, `start` requires some awkward quoting it seems, and this has created issues when trying to pass in parameters.

---

### The following script **does** work:

```
start "" "C:\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe" "G:\my pdfs\file1.pdf" "G:\my pdfs\file2.pdf"
start "" "C:\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe" "G:\my pdfs\file3.pdf" "G:\my pdfs\file4.pdf"
```

---

### The following script **does not** work

(it only opens the first file in each line, although the page and zoom are obeyed for that file):

```
start "" "C:\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe" /A "page=1&zoom=33.3" "G:\my pdfs\file1.pdf" "G:\my pdfs\file2.pdf"
start "" "C:\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe" /A "page=1&zoom=33.3" "G:\my pdfs\file3.pdf" "G:\my pdfs\file4.pdf"
```

**If I don't use `start`**, simply running: `"C:\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe" /A "page=1&zoom=33.3" "G:\my pdfs\file1.pdf" "G:\my pdfs\file2.pdf"` works fine with the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using start, specify the /A command and parameters for each file to be opened:

```
start "" "C:\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe" /A "page=1&zoom=33.3" "G:\mypdfs\file1.pdf" /A "page=4&zoom=55.5" "G:\my pdfs\file2.pdf"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had a follow-up question as well, if you had a few moments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775849/expanding-variables-in-a-windows-batch-file