# Expanding variables in a Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line-arguments, batch-processing, command-prompt

I run the following command in a Windows batch file:

```
start "" "C:\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe" /A "page=1&zoom=33.3" "G:\my pdfs\file 1.pdf" /A "page=4&zoom=55.5" "G:\my pdfs\file 2.pdf"
```

The works perfectly fine and opens both PDF files using their respective parameters. However, to make the process cleaner, I would like to start using variables in place of the PDF files (and even the PDF viewer executable). However, when I use variables, only the first PDF file opens:

```
set PDF1="G:\my pdfs\file 1.pdf"
set PDF2="G:\my pdfs\file 2.pdf"
start "" "C:\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe" /A "page=1&zoom=33.3" %PDF1% /A "page=4&zoom=55.5" %PDF2%
```

I should mention that I don't have this issue if I remove the `/A` command and the subsequent parameters for each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong quotation in `set` commands. Use `set "variable=value"` syntax as follows:

```
set "PDF1=G:\my pdfs\file 1.pdf"
set "PDF2=G:\my pdfs\file 2.pdf"
start "" "C:\PDF Viewer\PDFXCview.exe" /A "page=1&zoom=33.3" "%PDF1%" /A "page=4&zoom=55.5" "%PDF2%"
```

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference. `set`s with quotes around the entire variable preserve whitespace without including the quotes, while the way he has it preserves whitespace and includes the quotes.

Comment: @SomethingDark, I understand your logic, which is also why I thought this would work fine. But JosefZ's solution did resolve the issue. JosefZ, would you mind explaining why your way works but my way didn't?